# All the actions that need to be over the screen don’t work, but the rest of it does Vuetify / Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-7

I have install Vue and Vuetify in my project Laravel 7 but Vuetify is probably not installed properly. Because When I try to click to the button for open modal or when I search with autocomplete nothing happens…

The solution is write this in app.js document.body.setAttribute('data-app', true)
For install Vuetify I have follow this article :
[Install vuetify in laravel](https://medium.com/@ganeshkarkigk/thank-you-for-great-article-ae4e18eeb739)

When I test with this code for the modal or autocompletion nothing happens  :
[Autocompletion](https://codepen.io/pen/&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fautocompletes%2F)
[Modal](https://codepen.io/pen/&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdialogs%2F)

This is my app.js code :

````
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from "vuetify";

//this is the solution code
document.body.setAttribute('data-app', true)
//

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.Vue.use(Vuetify);
import ReadMore from 'vue-read-more';
Vue.use(ReadMore);

import { LMap, LTileLayer, LControl,LMarker,LCircleMarker,LTooltip,LFeatureGroup, LPopup, LControlLayers, LControlZoom, LIcon, LWMSTileLayer} from "vue2-leaflet";
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';


Vue.component('l-map', LMap);
Vue.component('l-icon', LIcon);
Vue.component('l-tile-layer', LTileLayer);
Vue.component('l-wms-tile-layer', LWMSTileLayer);
Vue.component('l-circle-marker', LCircleMarker);
Vue.component('l-marker', LMarker);
Vue.component('l-control', LControl);
Vue.component('l-control-layers', LControlLayers);
Vue.component('l-control-zoom', LControlZoom);
Vue.component('l-tooltip',LTooltip);
Vue.component('l-popup',LPopup);
Vue.component('l-feature-group', LFeatureGroup)

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('presentation-component', require('./components/Presentation.vue').default);
Vue.component('auth-component', require('./components/Auth.vue').default);
Vue.component('equipe-component', require('./components/Researchteam.vue').default);
Vue.component('atlas-component', require('./components/Atlas.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({

    vuetify: new Vuetify,
    el: '#app',


  });


```
````

Comment: Please provide code of what you have done so far. Since you are seeing the button and autocomplete component that means you are installed Vuetify correctly

Comment: @katsarov I have update my question !

Comment: Good! Now also add your component code where button and autocomplete are :) 
You can also check your browser console for errors when you click on button or make a change in the autocomplete

Comment: @katsarov I took this code for modal and this code for auto completion but nothing happens and I can't see anything in my console. Modal :https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdialogs%2F   Autocompletion : https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fautocompletes%2F

Comment: @katsarov The solution is write this // document.body.setAttribute('data-app', true) in app.js

Comment: You should have div with id="app" as wrapper around your components